# C - Queue not correctly storing values

Tags: c, memory, struct, queue, malloc

I am trying to implement a queue in C (using [this implementation](http://c-algorithms.sourceforge.net/doc/queue_8h.html)) where, given an input file with some number of lines each containing 5 values, a struct `Item` is created for that line and the values are assigned to the struct variables `value1`...`value5`. The struct is then placed in a queue, so the first line of the file will be the first struct in the queue, and the last line will be the last struct.

However, I am getting some weird behaviour when trying to read values from the structs in the queue. The end of the code segment below prints `value1` and `value5` as a debug check to make sure the values are correct. It should print `struct1->value1` and `struct1->value5` for both head and tail on the first iteration, and then `struct1->value1` and `struct1->value5` for head and `struct2->value1` and `struct2->value5` for tail on the second iteration, but instead it prints strange large values for both head and tail. (plus, it seems to forget about the first struct altogether.) What am I doing wrong here?

```
Sample file:
1 0 10 1 3
2 0 10 10 1
------------
/* read input file */
/* while the current line of the file is not null */
...
    /* create new item */
    Item *newItem = malloc(sizeof(Item));

    /* string tokenizer */
    /* adds tokens from current line to tokens[i] */
    ...

    /* set item variables */
    newItem->value1 = strtol(tokens[0], NULL, 10);  //should contain e.g. 1
    newItem->value2 = strtol(tokens[1], NULL, 10);  //should contain e.g. 0
    newItem->value3 = strtol(tokens[2], NULL, 10);  //should contain e.g. 10
    newItem->value4 = strtol(tokens[3], NULL, 10);  //should contain e.g. 1
    newItem->value5 = strtol(tokens[4], NULL, 10);  //should contain e.g. 3

    /* add to item queue */
    queue_push_tail(itemQueue, &newItem);

    /* check queue values */
    if(!queue_is_empty(itemQueue)) {                        //after two lines,
        Item *itemHead = queue_peek_head(itemQueue);        //this should differ...
        printf("Head: %d %d\n", itemHead->value1, itemHead->value5);
        Item *itemTail = queue_peek_tail(processQueue);     //...from this
        printf("Tail: %d %d\n", itemTail->value1, itemTail->value5);
    }
```

Expected output:

```
Head: 1 3   //when first line is read
Tail: 1 3
Head: 1 3   //when second line is read
Tail: 2 1
```

Actual output:

```
Head: 146752 -4196581   //when first line is read
Tail: 146752 -4196581
Head: 146792 -4196581   //when second line is read
Tail: 146792 -4196581
```

Comment: `queue_push_tail(itemQueue, newItem);` Note the value being pushed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
queue_push_tail(itemQueue, &newItem);
```

doesn't look right, it doesn't match how you peek items from the queue. If the queue is storing pointers, hand it `newItem`, not the address of `newItem`.

Comment: This works! I'm still learning the intricacies of pointers, so your help is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: If you pass the item by value, you leak memory. Beware that this change, while correct of itself, requires other changes too. Use [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.com) to check for leaks if you're on a supported platform.